# Calculating the integral $ \int_0^t \int_{-s}^s f(y) \,dy\,ds$ .

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I want to calculate the integral $\displaystyle \int_0^t \int_{-s}^s f(y) \, dy\,ds$ where $f(x)=\begin{cases}  1-x^2 & |x| \leq 1, \\ 0 & |x|>1. \end{cases}$

However, because $f(x)$ is defined separately for different intervals, I am having trouble calculating the integral associated with $dy$. I think I should divide the integrating interval by comparing $s$ and $1$ but because the outer integral is associated with $s$, I am confused about how should I proceed further.

Comment: Analyse two cases $|s|>1$ and $|s|\leq 1$.

Comment: @TheGrandDuke : And $|t|>1$ versus $|t|\le 1. \qquad$

Comment: The notation $\displaystyle \int_{-s}^s\cdots\,ds$ is potentially confusing: the $s$ in $\displaystyle \int_{-s}^s$ is not the same thing as the $s$ in $ds.$ But I think this may be considered not fatal to this way of expressing the problem. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $f(y)$ is an even function in a symetric interval $[-s,s]$ you can write

$$\int_0^t \int_{-s}^s f(y) \,dy\,ds=2\int_0^t \int_0^s f(y) \,dy\,ds$$

and changing the order of integration

$$2\int_0^t \int_0^s f(y) \,dy\,ds=2\int_0^t f(y) \int_y^t \,ds\,dy=2\int_0^t f(y)(t-y)\,dy$$

Now,

- If $1\leq t$ you have $\displaystyle 2\int_0^t f(y)(t-y) \,dy=2\int_0^1 (1-y^2)(t-y)\,dy=\frac{4 t}{3}-\frac{1}{2}$
- If $-1<t<1$ then $\displaystyle2\int_0^t f(y)(t-y) \, dy=2\int_0^t (1-y^2)(t-y)\,dy=t^2-\frac{t^4}{6}$
- If $t\leq -1$ you have $\displaystyle 2\int_0^t f(y)(t-y) \,dy=2\int_{0}^{-1} (1-y^2)(t-y)\,dy=-\frac{4 t}{3}-\frac{1}{2}$

$$\boxed{\displaystyle \int_0^t \int_{-s}^s f(y) \, dy \, ds = \begin{cases}  \frac{4 t}{3}-\frac{1}{2} & 1\leq t \\ t^2-\frac{t^4}{6} & -1<t<1 \\-\frac{4 t}{3}-\frac{1}{2} & t\leq -1\end{cases}}$$

**Edit:** About change order of integration

*The $s$ variable varies from $0$ to $t$ (two fixed values) and the variable $y$ varies from line $y=0$ to line $y=s$. That is, your domain is a triangle with vertices in $(0,0),(0,t),(t,t)$. Now, if you consider the inverse order: $y$ varies from $0$ to $t$ (two fixed values)  and $s$ varies from line $s=y$ to line $s=t$.*

Comment: Can I ask how changing the order of integration was done? This part seems really tricky to me.

Comment: The $s$ variable varies from $0$ to $t$ (two fixed values) and the variable $y$ varies from line $y=0$ to line $y=s$. That is, your domain is a triangle with vertices in $(0,0),(0,t),(t,t)$. Now, if you consider the inverse order: $y$ varies from $0$ to $t$ (two fixed values)  and $s$ varies from line $s=y$ to line $s=t$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: first consider
$$ \int_{-s}^{s} f(y) dy $$
see if you can write an expression for this in "two pieces" i.e. over two intervals for s